# AD5270 SPI potentiometer with Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, spi, sensors

I try to use a AD5270, 20KOhm SPI potentiometer for a personal project with my Raspberry Pi 3B+. I translate some Arduino libraries code to Python language but it looks like it won't work. I can't test if the potentiometer is good value configured so I read the resistor value and always get 0 from SPI register.

Problem : I don't know if my writing is well done because I can't probe the resistor. To know if it works, I read the register and always receive 0x00. Writing and/or reading won't work.

Expect : reading what I have written.

Hardware setup :

- !SYNC = CE0 = PIN24
- DIN = MISO = PIN19
- SDO = MOSI = PIN21
- SLCK = SCLK = PIN23

with 1uF ext capacitor and 3V3 supply (from Raspberry).

The datasheet of the AD5270 is available [here](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad5270_5271.pdf).

Minimalist code following the datasheet that won't work :

```
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(spi_bus, spi_device_select)
spi.max_speed_hz = 50000                                # Datasheet p7
spi.mode = 1                                            # CPOL = 0, CPHA = 1 (Datasheet p7)
# Datasheet example
data = [0x1C, 0x03]
r = spi.xfer(data)
print(r)
data = [0x05, 0x00]
r = spi.xfer(data)
print(r)
data = [0x08, 0x00]
r = spi.xfer(data)
print(r)
data = [0xC0, 0x00]
r = spi.xfer(data)
print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your hardware setup:

- DIN = MISO = PIN21 (through 10 Ohm resistor)
- SDO = MOSI = PIN19 (through 10 Ohm resistor)

DIN is input to AD5270, and therefore output of your RPI, so it should be MOSI. Same problem for SDO.

Comment: Beginner's mistake. I change it but it still don't work. I write the most minimalist code I can following the datasheet. And always receive [0x00, 0x00].

Comment: Please update your question with fixed pin layout. The minimalist code is great, I would probably just remove the long one, as it doesn't add to question. If you wire MISO directly to MOSI, eliminating AD5270, does it work as expected (you get what you send)?

Comment: I jump MISO and MOSI on the RPi and get this as output :
[14, 1], [2, 0], [4, 0], [96, 0] and I expected [xx, xx], [28, 3], [5, 0], [8, 0].

Comment: I tried the same code with `wiringpi.wiringPiSPIDataRW()` instead of SpiDev and get what I send but still don't work with the AD5270.

Comment: That's not how it works. you're supposed to get `[28, 3] ...", without the garbage at start. Send and receive happen at the same time. It seems the values you get are shifted by one bit, but correct otherwise.

Comment: Have you got an oscilloscope or logic analyser? It would be nice to confirm `CS` and other lines work as you expect them to work.

Comment: I had a pullup of 2K2 on SDO as datasheet mentionned and limit to 50MHz Spidev and get some new data : [0x0, 0x0], [0x1c, 0x3], [0x5, 0x0], [0x1, 0x0]. It looks really better !

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the tricks. Don't forget to add a pullup on SDO line and configure Spidev for the AD5270. This code work quite well :

```
# SPI test code for AD5270BRMZ-20
import time
import spidev

spi_bus = 0                                              # SPI0
spi_device_select = 0                                    # CE0

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(spi_bus, spi_device_select)
spi.max_speed_hz = 50000                                # Datasheet p7
spi.mode = 1                                            # CPOL = 0, CPHA = 1 (Datasheet p7)
spi.lsbfirst = False                                    # Datasheet p18

MAX_RESISTANCE      = 20000.0
WRITE_CTRL_REG      = 0x1C
READ_CTRL_REG       = 0x20
WRITE_RDAC          = 0x04
READ_RDAC           = 0x08
RDAC_WRITE_PROTECT  = 0x02

def AD5270_CalcRDAC(resistance):
    return int((resistance / MAX_RESISTANCE) * 1024.0)

def AD5270_ReadReg(command):
    data = [(command & 0x3C), 0]
    r = spi.xfer2(data)
    data = [0x00, 0x00]
    r2 = spi.xfer2(data)
    result = r2[0]
    result = (result << 8) | r2[1]
    return result

def AD5270_WriteReg(command, value):
    ui16Command = (command & 0x3C) << 8 | (value & 0x3FF)
    data = [(ui16Command >> 8) & 0xFF, ui16Command & 0xFF]
    spi.xfer2(data)

def AD5270_ReadRDAC():
    RDAC_val = AD5270_ReadReg(READ_RDAC)
    RDAC_val &= 0x03FF
    return ((RDAC_val) * MAX_RESISTANCE) / 1024.0

def AD5270_WriteRDAC(resistance):
    RDAC_val = AD5270_CalcRDAC(resistance)
    spi.xfer2([WRITE_CTRL_REG, RDAC_WRITE_PROTECT])
    AD5270_WriteReg(WRITE_RDAC, RDAC_val);
    return ((RDAC_val * MAX_RESISTANCE) / 1024.0)

while(1):
    AD5270_WriteRDAC(10000.0) # Write 10KOhm
    print(AD5270_ReadRDAC())
    time.sleep(1)

spi.close()
```